# cannot get http response content

Tags: c#, http, httpresponse

I'm trying to get the content of an HTTP response but I'm having some problems. I can get all the headers just fine but can't figure out how to get something readable out of the content. [here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onXcG.png)

[here's the response I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lzkU.png)

[here's what I should be getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4U1V.png)

Comment: Please consider posting code examples and responses as part of the question in the text form, and if you absolutely need to post as an image, post it inline instead of links to external sites.

Comment: Maybe trouble in `Encoding`? You can specify one when initializing `StreamReader`: `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are encountering Encoding problem, try reading stream like the following

```
(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), true))
```

Note the `true` second parameter on the StreamReader constructor tells it to detect the encoding from the byte order marks. I guess this might solve your issue.